# DownloadManager is not working on some Android devices

Tags: java, android, apk

DownloadManager does not seem to work on some Android devices. For example, the installation process seems to work on Samsung (Android 12) but on Huawei (Android 11) it does not work.

This is my code:

```java
    private void install(String url, String title) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                .setTitle(title)
                .setDescription("App Installation File")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        Uri destinationUri;
        if (download_type == DownloadTypes.LAUNCHER) {
            destinationUri = Uri.parse("file://" + launcher_url);
        } else if (download_type == DownloadTypes.MODULE) {
            destinationUri = Uri.parse("file://" + module_url);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        request.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
        download_id = dm.enqueue(request);
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

The file should be downloaded and installed normally, and should work on all Android devices.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the downloader process has write access to whatever `file` `Uri` that you are supplying.

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://" + launcher_url);` Please tell full path.

Comment: You mean this?

```java
    public static String launcher_url = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/launcher.apk";
    public static String module_url = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/module.apk";
```

Comment: Put your code please in your post on the place where it belongs. Not unreadable afterwards in comments.